# Laravel many-to-many select menu selected value based on the pivot value

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have a `many-to-many` relation as follows:

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class)->withPivot('number');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('number');
}
```

The migration I am using is this:

```
Schema::create('product_recipe', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('recipe_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('number');
    $table->primary(['product_id', 'recipe_id']);
});
```

Pretty standard stuff. Each product belongs to a category as well. In my view to add products to a recipe, I loop through the categories and their products, to display a nice list, like so:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    // Display $category information

    @foreach($category->products as $product)
        // Display product name and a select menu for the number
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The only issue I have with all this, is that when I edit this list later for a recipe, I cannot have the number selected in the number select menu. Well, I can actually, I am using this in my Product model to do so:

```
public function getNumber($recipe_id)
{
    return DB::table('recipe_product')
        ->whereProductId($this->id)
        ->whereRecipeId($recipe_id)
        ->value('number');
}
```

But this is not the way to do it I'm sure, there must be a better way to accomplish this somehow.

Comment: Tried `$product->pivot->number`?

Answer (score 0):

`withPivot()` allows you to retrieve all the columns you requested through the parent model, such as `$parent->pivot->some_column`

You are probably looking for something like this :

```
    @foreach($category->products as $product)
        // ...

        <select name="quantity">
            @for($i = 0; $i < 123; $i++)
                <option value="{{ $i }}"{{ $i == $product->pivot->number ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
        </select>
    @endforeach
```